# PHP Variable Error When Selecting From Table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a blog where I'm selecting the articles from a database using PHP.  The problem is that becuase of my search terms I'm hitting an error.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["cat"])){
   $cat = $_GET["cat"];
}else{
    $cat = "all";
};
?>
<?php
if($cat == "all"){
    $cat_var = "";
}else{
    $cat_var = "WHERE cat = '$cat'";
}; // NOTE THIS LINE
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["issue"])){$issue = $_GET["issue"];}else{
    $issue = "all";
};
?>
<?php
if($issue == "all"){
    $issue_var = "";
    $limit = 4;
}
else{
    $issue_var = "AND issue = '$issue'"; // NOTE THIS LINE
    $limit = 200;
};
?>
<?php
$count_posts_sql = "SELECT id FROM articles $cat_var $issue_var"; // NOTE THIS LINE
$count_posts_res = mysqli_query($con, $count_posts_sql);
$num_init_posts = mysqli_num_rows($count_posts_res);
//If None, Then Exit
if($num_init_posts == 0){
    header("Location: /home");
    exit();
}
...
?>
```

So my url would be `http://website.com/articles/all/2015-10`, which is what I want.  However `$cat_var` & `$issue_var` is causing the error because it's selecting:

```
SELECT * FROM articles AND issue = '2015-10' // NO WHERE STATEMEMT IS SHOWN
```

How do I overcome this error?

Comment: Put your criteria into an array. When you're generating your SQL, check to see if that array has contents, and if it does, cat `WHERE ` and implode your array onto it.

Comment: Sounds complicated for a beginner.  Just thinking, isn't there a way of doing something like `WHERE cat = ANYTHING`?

Comment: Add a `print_r($_GET);` to the top of the script, and show what you get from that in your question

Comment: You could always do `WHERE cat LIKE '%'`, which will match anything, but there may be performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get this going by sticking a `WHERE 1=1` in

```
$count_posts_sql = "SELECT id FROM articles WHERE 1=1 $cat_var $issue_var"; // NOTE THIS LINE
```

This is because you start off with an `AND value = 1` without starting the `WHERE` clause, which creates an invalid query.

Then take the `WHERE` out of this line and replacing it with an `AND`:

```
$cat_var = "AND cat = '$cat'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your where query string like this:

```
$where = 'WHERE 1 = 1 ';
```

and for there after you can concatenate depending on your inputs.